# AngularJS: Manipulate the $scope of an unknown $element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, attributes, scope, angularjs-directive

New to Angular.
I'm creating a directive (attribute) for global use through the whole project. I'm using a local storage function and my intention is to have the element, on which the attribute is situated, change its value/text accordingly. Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Email Address" ng-model='username' loadstorage="USERNAME" />
```

Here is the directive:

```
.directive("loadstorage", function (localStorage) {
        return function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
            $scope.$element = localStorage.get(attrs.loadstorage); 
        }
});
```

As you can imagine this doesn't work. So what I need is a way to manipulate the scope of the element that is calling the function.
What I tried so far is:

```
$element.val(localStorage.get(attrs.loadstorage));
```

It works but only when I remove the ng-model of the element, unfortunately I need it for other purposes in the project.

```
angular.element($element).scope();
```

With this I access the scope but cannot manipulate it. Here is a plunker example of what I'm talking about: http://plnkr.co/edit/FScDaj4YDIae8ZEs9ucx?p=preview
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive should probably manipulate the value through the `ngModel` controller ([docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController)):

```
.directive("loadstorage", function (localStorage) {
    return {
        require: ["ngModel"],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
            var ngModel = controllers[0],
                val = localStorage.get(attrs.loadstorage);
            element.val(val);
            ngModel.$setViewValue(val);
        }
    };
});
```

See forked plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/DZwTgrVNeLIbLXryscPy