# How to remember loaded views/frames in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am currently working on a large enterprise web platform which loads different web applications (html/js/silverlight) as views so it is almost like a container or a framework for accessing different types of web applications.

We are currently reviewing the migration to Angular however there's one problem (at least) which we can't address.

in the current non-Angular version when a user loads Application-A from within the framework and let's say types "ABC" in a text box then he decides to navigate away and load Application-B and after using that application when navigates back to Application-A he can still see "ABC" in the textbox in other words he has "Persistent Workspace" so every app that he loads whether it be Silverlight or Html/JS has the ability to be kept loaded into the memory.

Regardless of the right or wrong of this approach can anyone think of the way this can be implemented in Angular? a simple overview is enough.

[UPDATE]

Please note that we are dealing with iFrames for each of the web apps we currently load, so there's no model that we can persist to the browser storage or elsewhere. if all our apps where html/js based then we would have no problems as we could serialize the state of each view but since some are in Silverllight we can't do that. hope this clarifies.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can always synchronize Angular's state with the local storage of the browser. So there will have to be a unique key for every field in every form and use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846751/angularjs-manipulate-the-scope-of-an-unknown-element).

Alternatively, you can listen for the `$routeChangeStart` event ([docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.$route)) from within each controller that cares to save status. Then the controller can decide to serialize its state (or not) to the local storage. On controller initialization, the saved state must be retrieved.

Solutions involving the browser's [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) will not affect the server but will not be available to the user when he/she uses another computer. Otherwise, you should listen to the route events as before, but synchronize the "persistent workspace" with the server (slower, more development time).

Comment: Thanks, but how will this play right with Silverlight apps? will it mean that the XAP file will need to be reloaded? if yes, then it will mean a reload of the Silverlight app which is not acceptable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; from the question I thought that Silverlight apps manage their persistent workplace themselfs. Is the *same* app implemented *both* as Silverlight *and* HTML?

Comment: I agree that the question is a bit confusing, our App which is to be migrated is like a super smart iframe for loading many other independent apps written by other people within the organization. so when a user loads one application lets say Silverlight and types something in a textbox then decide to navigate away, we won't unload the page, we simply hide the iframe so that when comes back he could see the previous state he was one. hope it clarifies